# PHP help - requesting info from submitted forms

Tags: javascript, php

Is it possible to view the source of the next page of this website?

https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/

I want to use php to get the results of the next page, so that my company can have a automatic check on our drivers to see if they are taxed and MOT'd.

My car Reg is KS09 FSV and its a Volkswagen..

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to make HTTP requests and view the responses in PHP.  What have you tried?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Nothing yet as i really dont know how that part works. If you could point me in the right direction that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You should post the data to the https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/ViewVehicle page. If they use some security methods, then you're not able to do it.

BTW, Using PHP curl may help you to send a POST request to your target page.

Comment: Thanks. Im taking a look at this now, curl isnt something ive used to many times before to be honest..